# Setting TimeZone for Plone Events

Tags: timezone, plone, add-on

I'm pretty sure what I'm looking for can't be done out of the box by Plone (I'm running Plone 4), but I want to specify the timezone of each event. Is there a pre-existing add-on to support this that anyone knows of, or will I just need to create a new content type based on the ATEvent type? I couldn't find anything with regards to this, other than someone requesting it be added to events back in Plone 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm assuming I'll be creating a new content type soon but figured asking before hand couldn't hurt.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new event types in `plone.app.event` which is part of Plone since 5.0 do support timezones. You can have a look at the [repo](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.event).

Comment: I can not remember that plone.app.event would have support for time zones.